# Running Jest tests agains Vue tsx components

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, tsx

I am trying to create simple boilerplate for creating Vue tsx components but have an issue with configuring Jest testing the tsx component. I was wandering if anybody have already solved similar case or could share a clue about it.

Project here - https://github.com/zdravkov/vue-tsx-files-boilerplate

Greetings,

Answer (score 0):

If anybody reached this - I have resolved the issue by using this package - [typescript-babel-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-babel-jest).
The github repository is updated as well.